# ASP.NET MVC is throwing error "jQuery tDatePicker is not a function" in the console (Browser Developer Tools) when loading a view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, telerik-mvc

I am using an old version of Telerik for ASP.NET MVC.

When loading an ASP.NET MVC view I have seen in console (Developer Tools) that below error is thrown:

> jQuery tDatePicker is not a function

Using developer tools, I can see the line of code where this error is thrown. Below the line:

```
jQuery('#FromDate').tDatePicker({format:'MM/dd/yyyy', minValue:new Date(1899,11,31), maxValue:new Date(2100,0,1), selectedValue:new Date(2020,0,1)});
```

My ASP.NET MVC view has below includes:

```
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;

<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap2-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap2-toggle.js"></script>
```

If I remove the lines below:

```
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

...then that error disappears but another different error is shown. Anyway view is loaded correctly:

```
bootstrap.js requires jquery-1.9.1 or higher
```

I am a little bit lost and I do not know how to face with this kind of errors. Some help will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**:
I have registered datepicker client side library as suggested here by using razor syntax and by typing in below line in my _Layout.cshtml which is placed in my \Views\Shared folder (this is a master page I use in all my views):

> @(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group =>
>        group.Add("telerik.common.js").Add("telerik.datepicker.js")))

by error continues appearing in browser developer tools console (F12):

[image]

Also, icons beside datepickers fields are never shown, se below:

[image]

Comment: What is the tDatePicker function? Is that an official function that is in the Telerik API?

Comment: @TomelSafadi It's Telereik ASP.NET MVC Extensions. It is an old extension from Telerik.: @Html.Telerik().DatePicker()

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered correctly?
Register datepicker client side library:

```
$(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group =>
     group.Add("telerik.common.js").Add("telerik.datepicker.js")))
```

in your case of course

```
jQuery(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group =>
     group.Add("telerik.common.js").Add("telerik.datepicker.js")))
```

Another possibility to try (as I do not know your setup) - 
Note **id is NOT working** for some unknown reason - has imho never been fixed

```
@Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(m => m.EffectiveDate).Name("FromDate");
```

and using it like for testing(!)

```
 var datepicker = jQuery('#FromDate').data('tDatePicker');
 datepicker.value(new Date('1/1/2020')); // After testing replace with below
```

if that works you could implement your formats and min max the same way

```
 datepicker.format('MM/dd/yyyy');
 datepicker.minValue (new Date('1/1/1900')); 
 datepicker.maxValue(new Date('1/1/2100'));
 datepicker.selectedValue(new Date('1/1/2020'));
```

Comment: I have registered it but it continues throwing the same error (see my last update).

Comment: Have you tried the second possibility? I edited the code to extend your options

Comment: Yes, my Telerik datepicker controls are defined in the ASP.NET MVC view (cshtml) with this line of code (for example for one of them):

@Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(m => m.FromDate)

I do not manually type in anywhere the line of code shown in my first post : jQuery('#FromDate').tDatePicker(...)

This line is generated automatically (I saw it using browser developer tools (F12) by inspecting the code generated of the page because browser was pointing there due to the error described here, I mean, in design mode in visual studio, this line is not anywhere in the view - cshtml-).

Comment: The generated code misses imho the.data('tDatePicker'). Try to manualy test if (tDatePicker) is working at all It might be some weird config error. The original error indicates that the component (js) is not available but to narrow down you have to add code manually for test.

Comment: When you say to manually test if (tDatePicker) is working or it can be some weird config error, how can I test it manually or what config error do you refer to? How can I add code manually and where do i need to add this code for test? I am a little bit lost. Thanks in advance for your great help and support.

Comment: As I dont know you MVC version and the appropriate telerik setup I can only give you the link to the telerik manual: https://books.google.at/books?id=te8hqiUQomkC&pg=PA461&lpg=PA461 to test manualy add the html code to a generated page on the client (developer tools) and load it locally. Sometimes error messages are than more helpful. As a last resort you could use a datepicker extension which is installed via script tag. To narrow your search-> The component is not correctly installed -> registered -> used in that order!